# Table rentionion in snowflakes has any relation with timetravel setting?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Problem :Does it make sense to have time travel setting as 1 and retention setting as 30 days at table level (permanent table) in snowflakes .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no real setting called time travel.  `data_retention_time_in_days` is actually the setting that controls the duration of your time travel.  If you are asking whether an account setting of 1 day and a table-level setting of 30 days makes sense, then the answer is 'Yes'.  You can set this parameter at multiple levels (account, database, schema, table) to customize your data retention period based on those object levels.

Comment: Thanks Mike Walton.Yes i mean data_retention_time_in_days as time travel.Yes here is the confusion.Which setting will take precedence ?the one at table level or the one at account level?Say i have retention at table as 30 days and data_retention_time_in_days as 1 day.Will i be able query  5 days back data ?

Comment: It will always be the setting at the more granular level.  So, table overrides schema which overrides database which overrides account.

Comment: Thanks Mike Walton.So in this case  the answer for the below would be "YES"            
If  i have retention at table as 30 days and data_retention_time_in_days as 1 day.Will i be able query 5 days back data ?

Comment: assuming you mean data_retention_time_in_days at the account, database, and/or schema level, and your table is set to 30 days, then yes, you will be able to query that table for up to 30 days of history.

Comment: Thanks Mike Walton.If i decrease the retention at table level .Will that helps in reducing  the cost/credits on my over all bill .?

Comment: Not credits, but storage fees could be lower depending on how much churn the tables have (updates and deletes).

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned there is no setting for Time Travel. No tasks are required to enable Time Travel. It is automatically enabled with the standard, 1-day retention period.

To increase this retention period DATA_RETENTION_TIME_IN_DAYS parameter is used which can se set upto 90 days which can be set databases, schemas, and tables.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-time-travel.html

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F1pevMhm7lg

On top of that there is Fail-Safe period which provides a (non-configurable) 7-day period during which historical data is recoverable by Snowflake. This period starts immediately after the Time Travel retention period ends.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-failsafe.html